# How to extract coefficient in maple?

Tags: maple

I'm using maple for differentiation eguation. And I have a problem. I want to express the `d/dt(alpha(t))` variable held constant from this equation (a part for example):

```
-2*(diff(alpha(t), t))*sin(beta(t))*(diff(beta(t), t))*cos(psi(t))*
cos(theta(t))-2*(diff(alpha(t), t))*cos(beta(t))*sin(psi(t))*(diff(psi(t),t))*
cos(theta(t))-2*(diff(alpha(t), t))*cos(beta(t))*cos(psi(t))*sin(theta(t))*
(diff(theta(t), t))-2*(diff(beta(t), t))*sin(alpha(t))^2*(diff(alpha(t),t))*
cos(beta(t))*sin(psi(t)).
```

Any help is appropriate. Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to ask. Is it something that the `coeff` command will not handle?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a substitution. For example, let's assume that the large output involving derivatives was produced by running some code that I'll abbreviate as 'mycode;'. Then you can do this:

```
 output := mycode;
 new_output := subs(diff(alpha(t), t) = v,output);
```

Then, in new_output, instance of the symbol diff(alpha(t), t) will be replaced by the symbol v, and then you can use a function like coeff to strip the coefficients of v. This way, you can figure out what the trig-polynomial representation of output is.

Comment: But why should it be necessary to do either, `coeff(subs(diff(alpha(t),t)=v,output),v)` or `frontend(coeff,[output,diff(alpha(t),t)])` when direct application like `coeff(output,diff(alpha(t),t))` can succeed?

Comment: My suggestion was just to make an intermediate step using subs() so you can actually see the polynomial itself. The problem is that the coefficients are themselves symbolic entities that involve derivatives, and not just a vector of numbers. Also, judging by the Maple documentation for coeff() and coeffs(), they require that you specify the term (with order), as in if you want the x^2 cofficient, you specify coeff(myfun,x^2), etc. When wanting to see the trig polynomial representation here, that might not as useful as just looking at the function itself.